# What is the synonym for "Inclined" that is less technical?

Tags: synonyms

"My every conversation with them was inclined towards physics."

Also, Can someone come up with a better statement that adds more depth?

Comment: It may depend on exactly what you want to say. Using ***was inclined*** (or ***leaned***) is more appropriate if all the conversations were about physics *right from the beginning*. If they actually started off being about *other* things, but always ended up being about physics, that would be better expressed by saying *every conversation **turned to[wards]** physics*. But also note that *incline, lean* don't necessarily imply that physics was a particularly *significant* element in the conversation - just that physics had *some* relevance to what was discussed, or how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Incline* is not technical, but it does have a slightly "superior" sound to it.

A "simpler" synonym of *incline* is *lean*, and that will work in the same sense.

> My every conversation with them leaned towards physics.